# Error converting between string types in Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I'm new to using RCPP, and trying to write some code that essentially recreates a special case of the "outer" function in R. I have to vectors of strings, the first contains patterns, and the second contains sentences. I'm checking all sentences for all patterns, and attempting to return a matrix that is the number of times each pattern occurs in each sentence.

I've made some progress (though I'm sure some of your will be horrified by my code):

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::plugins("cpp11")]]

int addOccurrences(std::vector< std::string > &txt, std::vector< std::string > &pat) 
{ 
  int M = pat.size(); 
    int N = txt.size(); 
    int res = 0; 

    /* A loop to slide pat[] one by one */
    for (int i = 0; i <= N - M; i++) 
    {  
        /* For current index i, check for  
           pattern match */
        int j; 
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++) 
            if (txt[i+j] != pat[j]) 
                break; 

        // if pat[0...M-1] = txt[i, i+1, ...i+M-1] 
        if (j == M)   
        { 
           res++; 
           j = 0; 
        } 
    } 
    return res; 


} 


//[[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix freqMatrix (Rcpp::StringVector x,Rcpp::StringVector y)
{

    Rcpp::NumericMatrix matrx(x.size(),y.size());
    int i = 1;
    int j = 1;



    std::vector<std::string> xstrings(x.size());
    int k;
    for (k = 0; k < x.size(); k++){
        xstrings[k] = x(k);
    }

    std::vector<std::string> ystrings(y.size());
    int l;
    for (l = 0; l < y.size(); l++){
        ystrings[l] = y(l);
    }




    for(i = 1; i<=x.size(); i++)
        {
        std::vector< std::string > txt = xstrings[i];

        for(j = 1; j<=y.size(); j++)
            {
            std::vector< std::string > pat = ystrings[j];
            matrx(i,j) = addOccurrences(txt, pat);
            j = j + 1;
            }
         i = i + 1;
        }
return matrx;
}
```

I've gotten rid of most errors, but I'm getting stuck near the bottom. The error I'm getting says:

```
"conversion from '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >::value_type {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to non-scalar type 'std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >' requested
   std::vector< std::string > txt = xstrings[i];"
```

I get the same error for the second conversion `ystrings[j]'

I've tried several different ways to get this to work with both the 'std::vector' and 'Rcpp::StringVector', but I'm stumped.

Comment: `xstrings[i]` is a `std::strings`. You try to initialize a `std::vector<std::string>` from it. That won’t work. I don’t know what you want to do here: either omit the element access or create a range with one element, e.g., using `... txt{ xstrings[i] }`.

Comment: So change it to this: `std::string txt { xstrings[i] };` ? I'm trying to grab the ith element and save it as a string.

Comment: Should work although you can leave the initialization unchanged if you change the type. The main point was to create an `std::initializer_list<std::string>` to initialize a vector with just one element: `std::vector<std::string> txt{xstrings[i};`. What is needed will depend on the actual use.

Comment: Ah it compiled! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared the variable `xstrings` as a vector of strings.

```
std::vector<std::string> xstrings(x.size());
```

Then in this loop that by an unknown reason starts from 1 instead of 0 (and it seems can invoke undefined behavior when `i` is equal to `x.size()`)

```
for(i = 1; i<=x.size(); i++)

    {
    std::vector< std::string > txt = xstrings[i];
    //
```

you declared another vector of strings `txt` and are trying to initialize it with the object `xstrings[i];` that has the type `std;:string`.

There is no such a non-explicit constructor in the standard container std;:vector. So the compiler issues an error.

Instead you could write for example

```
    std::vector< std::string > txt( 1,  xstrings[i] );
```

Comment: oops, R habit initializing from 1. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is complaining because you are declaring a vector that can hold strings (i.e. txt) and trying to initialize it to a string (i.e. xstrings[i]). It'll probably also complain about the line:

```
std::vector< std::string > pat = ystrings[j];
```

Given that addOccurrences(...) checks a single sentence for a single pattern, shouldn't it be taking variables of type std::string as input parameters? This means it should be declared as follows:

```
int addOccurrences(const std::string & txt, const std::string & pat) 
{
     // do stuff...
}
```

The final loop inside freqMatrix could then be written as:

```
for(i = 1; i<=x.size(); i++)
{
    for(j = 1; j<=y.size(); j++)
    {
        matrx(i,j) = addOccurrences(xstrings[i], ystrings[j]);
    }
}
```